# Database Table without Primary Key

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table used for a message board (See below). I know best practices dictate creating a `Primary Key` but I can see no reason to create one. I will be searching mainly on (`UID, GRP_ID`) and will create an index on this. Deleting will be based on `Last_timestp`. In this scenario, should there be a `PK`?

```
CREATE TABLE CP.CHAT
(UID BIGINT NOT NULL, GRP_ID BIGINT NOT NULL, CHAT VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, LAST_TIMESTP TIMESTAMP);
```

Comment: However unlikely, you could have multiple rows with idential LAST_TIMESTP  values; and as LeBarton said in his answer, the amount of space taken up by a simple auto increment id field is neglible. Also, `BIGINT` is likely *EXTREME* overkill for user or group id's; it's likely even overkill for a auto incrementing primary key. `INT` is half the size; you could have ID, UID, and GRP_ID as INT and the table would be smaller than you've defined it above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primary keys are not required, and your table will work just fine.

Here are some reasons why I almost always use primary keys.

1. They let you uniquely target a row. If you have multiple rows with the exact same data, it can be tedious to delete it out.
2. They provide an implicit ordering to the table. If you are troubleshooting your database, the sequence of the keys tells you the order they were created.

Ultimately, the room taken up by PK are not going to be a huge overhead for the database in terms of storage space. It won't hurt to have it, but it could help to have it.

Comment: Just to be pedantic, they don't imply ordering unless they are auto-increment (or handled similarly); and I don't believe auto-increment officially guarantees the sequence either (but is very reliable for that purpose in my experience).

Comment: Had a feeling that I would'nt need a pk but just needed to be sure. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I see no need to tell you what a Primary Key is and what it is used for. It seems you already know it, and figured out the structure just fine.

The thing is, if you won't have any other tables which depends on this table, then your table setup will be sufficent for you. As you already have a UID column there, I say I would make that a PK, since it won't cost you much in terms of storage, but also could help you sort your table (by auto-incrementing integers) and would work as a selective for delete and update operations in the future.

Still couldn't figure out how you'll manage to delete records by Last_timestp values, though...

Comment: I was assuming UID was to indicate the user that created the message, so it wouldn't work for obvious reasons.

Comment: Oww... Couldn't guess that it was a Foreign Key of Users Table, sorry :)

Comment: I could have sworn the question originally specified that, but I must have just assumed it from the context the questioner supplied.

Comment: Delete will be like so... delete from chat where last_timestp > 1 WEEK AGO

Comment: I figured later. Thanks for getting back at me on this.

Comment: Also, you should make an habbit of upvoting the answers that helped you. Come back to upvote the answers that helped you once you'll have enough rep.